# request.getParameter() returns corrupted data - Java

Tags: java, encoding

In my project, from UI I am passing a string to the server like `account<s` using HTTP post method. This value is fetched in backend using `request.getParameter()` method of HTTPServlet. The getParameter() returns an encoded string. The `account<s` value is fetched as `account& lt;s`

Now in UI I need to display `account<s`. If the value is encoded as `account&lt;s`, then I can use html decoding in the UI part. But the encoded string has an additional space. Instead of `&lt;`, I am getting `& lt;`.

**jQuery Code:**

```
var params = {};
params.passVal = "account<s";
//ajax call
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:url,
    data:params,
    datatype:"json",
    async:false
}).success(function(json){
    //success notification
});
```

**Java Code:**

```
String receivedVal = request.getParameter("passVal");  //account& lt;s
```

I am using Apache Tomcat 7 and jquery v2.1.3

For all the encoded characters, a space is added between the 1st and the 2nd character. Why is it behaving like this? And how can I get the original data in Java?

Comment: Hmm. `request.getParameter()` is pretty reliable. Are you sure you are sending the parameter correctly? Is this from a browser form? Or some client code?

Comment: The parameter is passed from a browser form. And I checked the value that is passed in UI and it is `account<s`.

Comment: can u post the code ? like `HTML` and java `servlet`

Comment: please post you `html` element code which actually holds the value like `account<s` @DeepikaMasilamani

Comment: Can you post jquery version and application server? The jquery code is in a default html5 page? Have you checked the html source?

Comment: Do you use a servlet filter?

Comment: I tried to check the web.xml file to check for the servlet filters. But the statements with `<filter>` are commented. May I know the correct way to check if a filter is set or not? Sorry for the silly doubts. I am a newbie to web app. That is why.

Comment: Search your java classes for `@WebFilter` annotation. Use my SO @userId when writing a comment

Comment: No annotation is added like that @tak3shi

Comment: But a class is implemented from javax.servlet.Filter class. And HTML encoding is done here. The encoding process is incorrect in this file. That is why I am getting wrong encoded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurred because of a servlet filter class, in which the encoding process is defined. Instead of `&lt;`, it is coded as `& lt`. Thanks a lot @tak3shi for pointing out the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

An HTML entity (`&LT;`) is not URL encoding; you need to encode the `<` as `%3c`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am not encoding the values. When I pass `<` from UI, it becomes `& lt;` in backend